# Consumir datos de web service con php

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap

Hola lamento que sea algo simple para ustedes, pero soy novato en esto... busqué informacion en san google y veo todo confuso. Quiero enviar estos datos o XML A una url que me dieron.

NOTA: quiero hacerlo por php de preferencia, y si no hay, algún metodo que sea por js.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<entrada>
<nroPedido>0090000003</nroPedido>
<listaItems>
<descItem>Producto1</descItem>
<cantItem>1</cantItem>
</listaItems>
<volumen>0.50 </volumen>
<tipoServicio>101</tipoServicio>
<codDistEntrega>13</codDistEntrega>
<nomDestEntrega>Juanito</nomDestEntrega>
<apellDestEntrega>Alimanha</apellDestEntrega>
<codTipoDocDestEntrega>109</codTipoDocDestEntrega>
<nroDocDestEntrega>12345678</nroDocDestEntrega>
<telefDestEntrega>991276768</telefDestEntrega>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

el envío responderá:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <salida>
         <indicadorExito>1</indicadorExito>
         <msg>Se registró satisfactoriamente la Orden de Servicio para el pedido  [0090000003]</msg>
         <nroOrdenServicio>1807050000036</nroOrdenServicio>
         <listaPiezas>
            <nuPieza>180705000003601</nuPieza>
            <descCorta>EXPRESS - LI LI|JE</descCorta>
         </listaPiezas>
      </salida>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Mi duda es: Como envío y como recibo esos datos. (Si es posible que me hagan un ejemplo para entenderlo estaría buenísimo)
No se hacer esto agradecería me orienten por lo menos como se llama el tipo de envío o un ejemplo en alguna parte de internet y yo me leo la información.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara. La palabra *enviar*  es muy amplia. ¿Enviar cómo, en un email (¿como texto plano o en un adjunto?), a través de Dropbox, de Google Drive ... de cualquier otro  o ponerlo en una carpeta para que se lo descarguen...? ¿Y... lo de la *url que te dieron*, eso que significa? ¿Será más bien que quieres ofrecer ese archivo disponible para que sea consultado desde una URL bajo tu control? Si es posible edita la pregunta explicando con más claridad el problema y el contexto.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano ya lo edité, la verdad en lo que esperaba la respuesta estuve indagando más y almenos tengo el nombre, espero puedas ayudarme otra vez.

Comment: Parece que lo que necesitas implementar es un webservice basado en `SOAP`.  [Aquí tienes un buen punto de partida](http://php.net/manual/es/book.soap.php).  También puedes buscar ejemplos de webservice soap en PHP  en la red y encontrarás tutoriales. Si lees un poco de inglés, suelen estar mejor hechos los tutoriales en inglés.